# How to add a text clock widget?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Most of the tutorials use android studio 2.1.2 in which there is a text clock widget. But in android studio 3.1.2 there is no such widget. I also tried typing its code in the xml file but it just occupies a blank space. How to add a text clock widget in android studio 3.1.2??

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of android studio where you cannot find the textClock widget, a go around is to put a plain text widget where you want the text clock widget to be.  Then you go to the text tab beside the design tab and then edit the XML code, making it a textClock. Your new textClock code should look a bit like this.

```
<TextClock
   android : id ="@+id/textClock"
   android :layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android : format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
/>
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.